# CentOS 8 install gparted fails

Tags: centos, software-installation, gparted, polkit

In CentOS 8.0 Server with desktop, I am trying to install [gparted](https://gparted.org/). It's not in the native software app, so I tried:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install gparted
```

and when I ran the latter, I see

```
Error: Problem: conflicting requests
 - nothing provides PolicyKit-authentication-agent needed by gparted-1.0.0.4.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallables packages)
```

When I did, I saw:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1 day, 2:43:25 ago,.....
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

but `sudo yum install gparted` still fails in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encountered error which is missing policykit-authentication-agent dependency package does not look essential to run gparted.

You can try

```
dnf download gparted
sudo rpm -i gparted-downloaded-package-name.rpm --nodeps 
sudo gparted
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
sudo dnf install PolicyKit-authentication-agent
sudo dnf install gparted
```