# CentOS 8: Gparted requires polkit, where may I find it?

Tags: centos, software-installation, repository, gparted, polkit

In [a previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558134/centos-8-install-gparted-fails) I asked for help finding polkit so I could install gparted. The one answer I received allowed gparted's install by adding another repository, but led to other problems.

Now when I try to add other apps through Software I see

> Unable to download updates: failed to refresh cache: cannot update report 'getpagespeed-extras': repomd.xml parser error: Parse error at line: 45 (Entity 'hellip' not defined

`sudo yum update` did not resolve the problem.

How may I remove that error while keeping polkit?

Answer (score 1):

a `yum list polkit` or `yum provides polkit` shows that `polkit` comes from the base centos repository, at least it does under CentOS 7.7.  I don't expect that to have changed for CentOS 8.

so with a base install [from dvd iso] of centos which will include the centos *update* repository, that's where `polkit` is.

a `yum clean all` prior to doing a `sudo yum update` might fix your problem... provided it's not caused by something else.

the only other thing you could possibly *need* is the EPEL repository which can be found here:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

for centos 8: `yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm`

I know `gparted` comes from EPEL.

Comment: Tried `yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm` which _[FAILED] epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm: Status code: 404 for https://dl.fedoraproject.org/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm_ and wget doesn't find it, either, yet PING confirms 60 ms to connect to dl.fedoraproject.org

Comment: it looks like the epel sight might be down at the moment, it happens.  happened to me a couple weekends ago with centos 7.... down as in the packages being served out to anyone doing a yum update is not available.

Comment: if the error doesn't resolve itself in a day then i would ask this question at forums.centos.org

Comment: Try https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm now.  Works for me.